AttributeError: 'Decompressor' object has no attribute 'process', while performing scrapy scraping
I am doing a tutorial on scrapy scraping and want to scrap the data from a website. I created the scrapy project and opened the scrapy shell to test it. However, the requests gets redirected and gets status 301 and this causes an AttributeError: 'Decompressor' object has no attribute 'process'.
My input to scrapy shell:
r = scrapy.Request('http://worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country')
fetch(r)

Output
2024-05-01 01:26:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/> from <GET https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country>

AttributeError: 'Decompressor' object has no attribute 'process'

The request gets redirected and this leads to an AttributeError. Have anyone encountered this issue? Thanks in advance!

I too am getting a redirect but I am not getting the attribute error... what version of scrapy are you running?

I am currently using scrapy 2.11.1

You have brotlipy installed, which is API-incompatible with Brotli but uses the same import name, so Scrapy thinks the latter is installed and tries to use it. This is fixed by https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/6261 but the fix is not released yet. In any case, having brotlipy installed is a bad idea, you should use Brotli instead.
